# Read tables of sql server from postgres

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

I'm trying to access sql server tables through postgres, I tried using [this](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers#odbc_fdw) wrapper for databases with an ODBC driver, but the lastest version is compatible only with the 9.1 version of Postgresql

I need a odbc driver for Postgresql 9.3

This is my sql shell (psql) when I try to do a CREATE EXTENSION statement

```
postgres=# CREATE EXTENSION odbc_fdw;
ERROR:  biblioteca «C:/Archivos de programa/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib/odbc_fdw.dll» inc
ompatible: versión no coincide
DETALLE:  Servidor tiene versión 9.3, biblioteca es versión 9.1.
postgres=#
```

The error says "library «C:/Archivos de programa/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib/odbc_fdw.dll» inc
ompatible: version doesn't match
DETAIL: the server version is 9.3 and the lib version is 9.1"

From what I searched, there's no further version of odbc_fdw.dll

Am I missing something? will I have to look something else?

Comment: Possible workarounds - another direction: LINKED SERVER from SQL Server to Postgres with ODBC - and then push data to some temp table at Postgres and then read it and process. Or - expose your data via webservice.

Answer (score 0):

You may get the odbc_fdw for pg 9.3 at :
https://osdn.net/projects/sfnet_postgresql-mingw-w64/downloads/odbc_fdw-9.3-x64.tar.gz/
Good luck